# Core plot doesn't display any data below the x axis

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am using core plot to make this scatter plot graph. Is there a way to make it so that all the points in my graph will be displayed above the x-axis? There are no negative values in my graph. All the values in my graph are from 60.00 to 64.00. Right now my graph looks like this

[image]

But is there a way I can make sure that there are no data points that are displayed below the x axis and to the left of the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly where the points are going to lie, then you can set the **orthogonalCoordinateDecimal** value of the axes so that all of the points are found within the first quadrant.  This code is taken from DatePlot.m in the Plot_Gallery_iOS example project:

```
//Found in renderInLayer
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);

/* Change the 2.0 to another value and the x axis will intersect the y axis at y = newVal*/
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(newVal);

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.5);
y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 5;

/* Change the oneDay to another value and the y axis will intersect the x axis at x = newVal*/
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay); //oneDay * 2
```

You can update this at any time if you get dynamic data.  Just get reference to the axis you need (graph -> axisSet -> x/y Axis) and then update it with the new value.

Comment: Can you include more code so we can see a little more of what is going on in your set up?

Answer (score 0):

Set the vertical plotrange so that it starts at 0, not at the lowest value in your dataset:

```
...
CPTPlotRange *plotRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: CPTDecimalFromDouble(0)
                                                       length: CPTDecimalFromDouble(maxValue)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = plotRange;
plotSpace.yRange = plotRange;
...
```

maxValue is the largest value in your dataset.